# Check URL/Website if it can be embedded or use in iFrame

Tags: php, http, iframe, header

Is there a way to check or validate any **URL**/**Domain** if it is possible to embed them in an ***iframe***? Some website/domain "**header response**" doesn't give an `"X-Frame-Options"` result.

Using **JavaScript** or **PHP**.

TIA

Comment: It could also be an `Content-Security-Policy` header with the `frame-ancestors` directive. And some pages might still be using JavaScript "framebreakers", although you can probably defeat those via the `sandbox` attribute of the iframe. (Whether everything else in such a page will still work then, is hard to say though.)

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for this guide. I will try this and will share my experience and output as well.